# Grouped bar plot in MATLAB based on column values in a table

Tags: matlab, plot, bar-chart, grouped-bar-chart

I want to plot a grouped bar graph like in the figure below:

[image]

I've included a mock-up of the data I'm using:

[image]

I want to group the bars by `SampleSite`, label them by `SampleName`, and color them by `Category`. I've tried the following code, and while it gives me something close to what I'm looking for, I'm unsure how to get the data grouped and colored by the column values.

```
y1= samples(MockUp_Data.SampleSite== "Site1", :);
y2= samples(MockUp_Data.SampleSite== "Site2", :);
y3= samples(MockUp_Data.SampleSite== "Site3", :);

y= [y1;y2;y3];
bar(y.Data)
set(gca, 'xticklabels', char(y.SampleName), 'fontweight', 'bold', 'fontsize', 12)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I want to group the bars by `SampleSite`, label them by `SampleName`, and color them by `Category`.

[`pivot`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/pivot.html) your current "long" table into a "wide" table:

- One `SampleSite` (group) per row
- One `Category` (color) per column

```
P = pivot(MockUp_Data, ...
    'Rows', 'SampleSite', ...
    'Columns', 'Category', ...
    'DataVariable', 'Data')

% P =
%
%   3x5 table
%
%     SampleSite    Bulk    Coarse    Fine    Mud
%     __________    ____    ______    ____    ___
%
%      "Site 1"     4.5        6       2      3.1
%      "Site 2"     5.5      6.7       8       10
%      "Site 3"      12      3.3       2        5
```

Now we have *x* in column 1, *y* in columns `2:end`, and legend entries in headers `2:end`:

```
bar(P{:,1}, P{:,2:end})
legend(P.Properties.VariableNames{2:end})
```

[image]

---

Note that your text description and mock figure are flipped (former is grouped by `SampleSite`, latter is grouped by `Category`). To follow your mock figure, flip the rows and columns while pivoting:

```
P = pivot(MockUp_Data, ...
    'Rows', 'Category', ...
    'Columns', 'SampleSite', ...
    'DataVariable', 'Data')
bar(P{:,1}, P{:,2:end})
legend(P.Properties.VariableNames{2:end})
```

[image]